# How to stop running Visual Studio as Administrator

Tags: visual-studio, permissions

When building a Windows Service I found that I needed to be running Visual Studio as Administrator and perhaps foolishly, took these steps on [How to Run Visual Studio Permanently as Administrator](https://improveandrepeat.com/2021/01/how-to-run-visual-studio-permanently-as-administrator/?unapproved=49088&moderation-hash=6cb2a6df552b3c511994009f359ceede#comment-49088).

That all worked fine but I now find that when trying to debug Apps that integrate with Outlook, they won't work if Outlook is already running, so I want to run Visual Studio as normal i.e. not as Administrator.

Does anyone know how to undo this troubleshooting change? Could it require a registry edit?

Comment: You should be able to follow the same procedure again, just uncheck the checkbox in step 4.

Comment: PMF - you are my hero. I have tried so many things to resolve this and although I HAD tried re-visiting the Troubleshooter previous, I must have done something wrong as it worked fine this time  - many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks to @PMF for solving this. As suggested, following the same procedure and unchecking the checkbox in step 4 works.